# Countdown Timer added in HTML, showing issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, countdowntimer

Please advice on a concern.

I have a created a landing page with a countdown timer, using HTML, CSS & JS. The countdown timer does works however stops working after sometime and shows the default values as set to 00:00:00:00.

Please advise, I do not seem to rectify any mistake in coding.

**HTML code as written**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Countdown Timer</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class = "sec">
            <h1 class = "coming">COMING SOON</h1>
        </section> 
        <header>
            <div class="heading">
                <h1>University <span>of </span>Saskatchewan</h1>
                <h2>Arts & Science College</h2>
                <div class="countdown">00 : 00 : 00 : 00</div>
                <div class="def">Days : Hours : Mins : Secs</div>
                <style>
                    .def{
                        color: white;
                        justify-content: center;
                        text-align: center;
                        margin-top: 10pt;
                 
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS code as written**

```
let newDate = new Date("Dec 8, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
let t = setInterval(sec, 1000);

function sec () {

    let todayDate = new Date().getTime();

    let diff = newDate - todayDate;

    if (diff  > 0){
        let d = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        if (d < 10) { d = "0" + d;}
        
        let h = Math.floor(((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000*60*60)));
        if (h < 10 ) {h = "0" + hours;}

        let m = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        if(m <10) {m = "0" + m;}

        let s = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        if (s < 10 ){s = "0" + s;}

        let newTime = `${d} : ${h} : ${m} : ${s}`

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = newTime;


    
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have an error, `h = "0" + hours` is not defined

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't saw it, let me fix the error and update.

Comment: Are you sure this code work? It seems that the element does not have the id 'countdown'. Actually 'countdown' is a class of that element. Does the console show any errors when it stop working?

Comment: @Raxel21 fixed the bug however still the same situation, the countdown is not working.

Comment: @MarcosAlexandre the countdown was working before, however now it has fully hault on the default values 00 : 00 : 00 : 00, should I assign an id to countdown and HTML and try adding that in JS ?

Comment: change this: `document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = newTime;` to this: `document.querySelector(".countdown").innerHTML = newTime;`

Comment: Yes... Either do like said by @Raxel21 or add an id attribute to element: id='countdown'.

Comment: Yes ! This worked, I gave an id to the <div> that was managing the countdown part in HTML as @MarcosAlexandre said. The countdown is working now and if I do change the timezone, the countdown manages to change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Raxel21 for the help, highly appreciated.

Comment: @MarcosAlexandre Thank you to you as well ! Swift responses are much appreciated. If there is any trouble will surely let you know.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to contact in case o need. manalista at gmail dot com. Best regards.

Comment: @OmarAsim You are welcome, I also recommend you to avoid errors of undefined variables or other errors: ESLint